# Handle Selenium RC open method failure (404)

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-rc

I have a loop that checks for the existence of urls. If one does not exist Selenium exits:
***XHR ERROR: URL = http://localhost/pages/156.php Response_Code = 404 Error_Message = Not Found.***

If i catch the exception:

```
try {
     $this->selenium->open($url);
}
catch(PHPUnit_Framework_Exception $e) { echo "caught\n"; }
```

Anything i do afterwards gives me this error:
***ERROR Server Exception: sessionId should not be null; has this session been started yet?***

I even tried to set the exception as expected:

```
$this->selenium->setExpectedException('PHPUnit_Framework_Exception');
```

But still the session is stopped and the test is completed. How can i make Selenium keep testing the urls? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create new selenium instance for every url!

```
$this->selenium = new Testing_Selenium("*firefox", "http://your-app-under-test.org/");
$result = $this->selenium->start();
$this->selenium->open("/the-page-to-test.php");
```

or see http://pear.php.net/package/Testing_Selenium/docs/0.4.3/Selenium/Testing_Selenium.html#method__construct for reference, there are more arguments to the constructor.

Comment: Thanks Moritz, you are right. Actually i can catch the exception and then start a new session. This works!